# Meteor Tutorial - Tracker is not defined

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, meteor

I'm doing the Meteor + Ionic tutorial and, after having corrected several errors, I'm completely stuck with one.

Changing my main.ts code with this one

```
import 'meteor-client';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'; 
import { MeteorObservable } from 'meteor-rxjs'; 
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'; 
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

Meteor.startup(() => {   
    const subscription = MeteorObservable.autorun().subscribe(() => {

        if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
            return;
        }

        setTimeout(() => subscription.unsubscribe());
        platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);   
    }); 
});
```

Throws the next error

> ReferenceError: Tracker is not defined at autorun
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:178469:13) at
>   Observable._subscribe
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:178480:27) at
>   Observable._trySubscribe
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23023:25) at
>   Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23011:93)
>   at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:57:65 at maybeReady
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:123856:57) at
>   HTMLDocument.loadingCompleted
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:123868:9) at t.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660) at r.runTask
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834) at e.invokeTask [as
>   invoke] (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16794)

I've checked all the dependencies and everything is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fresh node install solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that subscribe isn't directly connected to autorun. Try splitting the two up with this:

```
 const sub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('mySubscriptionForSomeData');
    const autorun = MeteorObservable.autorun();
    Observable.merge(sub, autorun).subscribe(() => {
        this.jobs = SomeCollection.find().zone(); // Data is ready here
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err); // error fetching data
    }, () => {
        console.log('This will print always, whether data is fetched or err happened');
    });
```

Source: https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-rxjs/issues/98

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Finally a fresh node installation solved the problem. Thanks anyway